# Add a (child) button element to a div for each array in a JSON object, and add child buttons (to the array buttons) for each object within the arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, ajax, object

I am trying to create a button for each JSON array withing the JSON object. There are 2 arrays. I then want to append child buttons onto these 2 buttons for each object within the arrays (for which there are 6 each). I have written this code which in my head should work but it does not, it only produces an error. I'll include my JS code. I've been trying for a few days and am really running out of time so any advice would be great.

```
<body>
<div id="title"> <!--print how many modules altogether here with .length-->
</div>
<div id="nav">
</div>


<script>
    $( document ).ready(function() { 
        $.getJSON( "courses.json", function( json ) {
            for (var i in Object.keys(json)) {
                var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
                document.getElementById("nav").appendChild(btn);
                btn.id = "myBtn";
                    $.each(i, (function(j) {
                        var btns = document.createElement("BUTTON");
                        document.getElementById("myBtn").appendChild(btns);
                        }))
                    }
            })
    })

</script>
</body>
```

//JSON:

```
{
"semester1": [
        {"code":"CS6100", 
        "title":"Multimedia Authoring", 
        "Credit Weighting":5, 
        "Content":"Programming in Processing", 
        "Assessment":{"CA":40,"exam":60}, 
        "link":"https://www.ucc.ie/admin/registrar/modules/?mod=CS6100"},

        {"code":"CS6101",  
        "title":"Web Development for Digital Media", 
        "Credit Weighting":5, 
        "Content":"Web Development with programming in Client and Server Side Languages", 
        "Assessment":{"CA":40,"exam":60}, 
        "link":"https://www.ucc.ie/admin/registrar/modules/?mod=CS6101"},

        {"code":"CS6102", 
        "title":"Graphics for Interactive Media", 
        "Credit Weighting":5, 
        "Content":"Programming in Python. The principles, practices, technologies and critical frameworks associated with the practice of graphic design for digital media. Develop understanding of the creative and technical aspects of image capture, editing and manipulation. Production of graphics for digital media using industry-standard tools.", 
        "Assessment":{"CA":40,"exam":60}, 
        "link":"https://www.ucc.ie/admin/registrar/modules/?mod=CS6102"},

        {"code":"CS6103", 
        "title":"Audio and Sound Engineering", 
        "Credit Weighting":5, 
        "Content":"Introduction to the technologies and techniques used in digital audio. Physics of sound and the psycho-physiological basis of hearing. Sound engineering, production and post-production.", 
        "Assessment":{"CA":40,"exam":60}, 
        "link":"https://www.ucc.ie/admin/registrar/modules/?mod=CS6103"},

        {"code":"CS6104", 
        "title":"Digital Video Capture and Packaging", 
        "Credit Weighting":5, 
        "Content":"Develop understanding of the planning, production and post-production of digital video. Application and evaluation of industry-standard tools in capturing, processing and packaging digital video.", 
        "Assessment":{"CA":40,"exam":60}, 
        "link":"https://www.ucc.ie/admin/registrar/modules/?mod=CS6104"},

        {"code":"CS6111", 
        "title":"3D Graphics and Modelling", 
        "Credit Weighting":5, 
        "Content":"Tools, techniques and processes involved in 3D graphics design, modelling and rendering. Create appropriate models of 3D objects and scenes. Solving problems in curve, surface and solid modeling.", 
        "Assessment":{"CA":40,"exam":60}, 
        "link":"https://www.ucc.ie/admin/registrar/modules/?mod=CS6111"}
        ],
```

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: `id`s should be unique

Comment: And change the "BUTTON" element to lowercase

Comment: TypeError: right-hand side of 'in' should be an object, got string.. it is referring to the jquery library i have sourced at the top, which I guess must just mean something is very wrong in my code

Comment: Yeah i wanted to set their class names but needed them to be id's so i could append to them

Comment: You can still append to class names. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName

Comment: Try adding a `console.log(i);` line between `btn.id = "myBtn"` and `$.each(i, (function(j) {`

Comment: thanks for that link! Ok did that it printed 0. Also changed the id to a class and changed buttons to lower case

Comment: So is your problem fixed? If it is, you can answer your own question if you want. If it isn't, could you tell me what's still broken?

Comment: Still not fixed unfortunately, producing the same red error with the addition of a yellow error stating -> Source map error: request failed with status 404
Resource URL: https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js

Answer (score 0):

```
for (var i in Object.keys(json))
```

iterates over each `i` in `Object.keys(json)`, which returns an array of the keys in an object (as strings). `$.each` expects an array or object, but you pass it the index `i`, which is a string (like "semester1").

So you have two options: either you pass `json[i]` to `$.each` instead of just passing `i`, like this:

```
...
    $( document ).ready(function() { 
        $.getJSON( "courses.json", function( json ) {
            for (var key in Object.keys(json)) {
                var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
                document.getElementById("nav").appendChild(btn);
                btn.id = "myBtn";
                $.each(json[key], function(index, course) {
                    var btns = document.createElement("BUTTON");
                    document.getElementById("myBtn").appendChild(btns);
                })
            }
        })
    })
...
```

Or you change the first `for` loop so that it iterates over the array of courses itself as well as the key "i". You can do this using `$.each`, just like you are doing in the other part of your program:

```
...
    $( document ).ready(function() { 
        $.getJSON( "courses.json", function( json ) {
            $.each(json, function(key, semester_courses) {
                var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
                document.getElementById("nav").appendChild(btn);
                btn.id = "myBtn";
                $.each(semester_courses, function(index, course) {
                    var btns = document.createElement("BUTTON");
                    document.getElementById("myBtn").appendChild(btns);
                })
            })
         })
    })
...
```

I think this will help you solve your problem. If you are still getting errors just leave a comment and I will update my answer. Also please **update your question with the most recent version of your code** that is producing the error. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `semester1` and the like are the only properties in the main JSON object you're getting:

```
$(function(){ // load
$.getJSON('courses.json', function(json){
  $.each(json, function(semester, array){
    $.each(array, function(index, obj){
      var b = document.createElement('input'); // not a submit button - I just prefer this style
      b.type = 'button'; b.id = semester+'_'+index; $('#myButton').append(b);
      $(b).on('click', function(){
        console.log(obj); // should be the Object
      });
    });
  });
});
}); // end load
```